# golang: net.Conn: check conn status

Tags: go

I encountered a strange behavior of the conn.Read:
let's presume that I have a couple of  functions for testing net.Conn:

```
package example

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func CheckConn(conn net.Conn) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now())
    var one = []byte{}
    _, err := conn.Read(one)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Net err: ", err)
    }
    if err == io.EOF {
        return conn, err
    }
    var zero time.Time
    conn.SetReadDeadline(zero)
    return conn, nil
}

func CheckConnWithTimeout(conn net.Conn) (net.Conn, error) {
    ch := make(chan bool, 1)
    defer func() {
        ch <- true
    }()
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-ch:
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            log.Println("It works too long")
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()
    return CheckConn(conn)
}
```

And I want to implement tests for it, lets start with this one:

```
package example

import (
    "io"
    "net"
    "testing"
)


func TestClosedConn(t *testing.T) {
    server, client := net.Pipe()
    client.Close()
    defer server.Close()
    _, err := CheckConn(server)
    if err != io.EOF {
        t.Errorf("Not equal:\nExpected: %v\nactual: %v", io.EOF, err)
    }
}
```

this works pretty well, we will receive io.EOF from CheckConn function, lets add one more test:

```
func TestClosedConnAfterWrite(t *testing.T) {
    server, client := net.Pipe()
    go func() {
        client.Write([]byte{0xb})
    }()
    client.Close()
    defer server.Close()
    _, err := CheckConn(server)
    err = nil
    if err != io.EOF {
        t.Errorf("Not equal:\nExpected: %v\nactual: %v", io.EOF, err)
    }
}
```

looks like the first test, but we wrote to the client before(?) it was closed.

And this will not pass!

conn.Read will return &errors.errorString{s:"EOF"}, instead of io.EOF, so CheckConn will return error == nil,

It looks so weird!

But let's continue the tests, now I want to check unclosed connections:

```
func TestActiveConn(t *testing.T) {
       server, client := net.Pipe()
       defer client.Close()
       defer server.Close()
       _, err := CheckConnWithTimeout(server)
       if err != nil {
           t.Errorf("Not equal:\nExpected: %v\nactual: %v", nil, err)
       }
}
```

I think you noticed that I use the function with a timeout just because SetReadDeadline will not work in this case(I have no idea why!)

So what is going wrong in last two test cases? Is there a normal way to test the connection? Why SetReadDeadline is not working in this case?

Comment: "but we wrote to the client before(?) it was closed." I bet its the other way around.

Comment: I would not bet on any one option) But I've added time.Sleep and log after client.Write to be sure. Nothing has changed so I removed it to make it easier to read.

Comment: Typical Go approach is to start goroutine to read connection.  With this approach, there's no need to check status of channel separate from the Read return values.

Comment: You cannot check the status of a `net.Conn`, you simply read from it.

Comment: yeah, and this is exactly what I do, I try to simply read from it, so I have to check the errors, all my post just about it.

Comment: Reading 0 bytes isn't reading, and isn't guaranteed to do anything useful. Your second test has no synchronization with its goroutine, which may not run until after the test, or at all, and any error it encounters is discarded. Don't try to "check" connections, just use them and handle the errors appropriately.

Comment: ->  Your second test has no synchronization with its goroutine, which may not run until after the test
yes, but please, look at error, it is very unexpected